# UINavigation bar bottom line appears after UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Navigation bar, with segmented control under it and it looks like this:

[image]

So there is no bottom line since i removed it this way:

```
 for (UIView *view in self.navigationBar.subviews) {
        for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
            if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [view2 removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i open Archive ViewController, that contains UISearchDisplayController, and i start searching i get normal uisearchDisplayController screen like this:

[image]

Now, when i Click cancel and go back to "Home" ViewController, bottom line appears again:

[image]

It's weird, if i just go back from Archive to Home, without opening SearchController it doesnt appear.

I tried removing bottom line in ViewDidAppear in "Home" ViewController same way as i posted above, but it's kinda late, line appears first then disappears after 1-2 seconds. 
I Also tried setting navigation bar shadow image to nil and it didn't do the job.

So my question is how to remove it after appearing again, any idea where should i call method i have for removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `AppDelegate.m` write this code hope that will help you.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; 
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

    return YES;
}
```